The results of math.fsum is different from a simple loop sum in python
I'd like to understand why the two methods of summing a list of floating point numbers differs by exactly 32.0?
import math

nums = [26015151255025000.,26015151255025000.,26015151255025000.,26015151255025000.,26015151255025000.,26015151255025000.,26015151255025000.,26015151255025000.,26015151255025000.]

math_fsum_result = math.fsum(nums)

loop_result = 0.0
for n in nums:
    loop_result += n

print(format(math_fsum_result, '.1f'))
print(format(loop_result, '.1f'))

Which produces:
234136361295224992.0
234136361295224960.0
It is understood that both are accumulating rounding errors but the inconsistency of exactly 32.0 seems weird.
For the record the correct value calculated with decimals is:
234136361295225000.0

If a simple loop did always produce the same result as fsum, fsum wouldn't exist.

Why do you think 32 is weird? The fsum function performs partial sum tracking to try to keep the "I can't actually do this with fixed-precision floating point numbers" error lower than naive summation, so getting a result that differs by a single bit near the LSB compared to naive summation is pretty much in line with that?

I have never used that method, but I think the key difference is how the algorithm works in both cases. For math itself, the algorithm tends to produce a precise and better result, while the standard calculation in Python, using loops and calculations, truncates the result, reducing the precision.
Also not to mention dealing with loops take more time compare to math.fsum().Instead of looping there is built in sum() function that can do the same.If you want to learn more about sum and math.fsum()
refer this post : What is the difference between built-in sum() and math.fsum() in Python 3.12?

Confirmed the answer is differences in precision due to the summation algorithm in use, the difference being exactly 32 is just the difference in precision.
The python fsum in the cpython reference implementation here has the details on the summation algorithm used: cython mathmodule

Realistically, this is a form of Is floating point math broken?
Internally, the two implementation results only differ by a single bit, but this has such a noticeable effect due to the magnitude of the values and also their proximity to actually being integers, which makes the result feel ugly
math.fsum specializes in producing a more accurate result at the cost of much more accounting and runtime, and does just that! "Avoids loss of precision by tracking multiple intermediate partial sums."
(ref for binary display 1-liner used below!)
>>> int(math.fsum(nums))  # close to true value
234136361295224992
>>> int(sum(nums))        # naive sum (Python 3.11)
234136361295224960
>>> sum(map(int, nums))   # true result using integer math
234136361295225000
>>> for f in (234136361295224992., 234136361295224960., 26015151255025000.):
...     print(f'b{struct.unpack(">Q", struct.pack(">d", f))[0]:064b}')
... 
b0100001110001001111111101000111000111101101000000000100100000101
b0100001110001001111111101000111000111101101000000000100100000100
b0100001101010111000110110010100100011010010101010101110101011010

See how these values with much smaller magnitudes behave - it's much more obvious that the very small parts don't matter to the result and are troublesome to represent
>>> sum([1.2, 2.2])
3.4000000000000004
>>> math.fsum([1.2, 2.2])
3.4000000000000004
>>> for f in (1.2+2.2, 3.4):
...     print(f'b{struct.unpack(">Q", struct.pack(">d", f))[0]:064b}')
... 
b0100000000001011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110100
b0100000000001011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011

Really any guarantees about the accuracy of small fractions of IEEE 754 floats and further that any particular algorithm or implementation1 which accepts them will always have a known or precise inaccuracy, is simply fraught with peril
Some general guidelines which can help

never compare the values directly, but verify that they are within some tolerance of accuracy
for example, NumPy provides numpy.isclose(), which defaults to a "relative tolerance" of 1e-05 and an "absolte tolerance" of 1e-08
>>> numpy.isclose(234136361295225000, 234136361295224960)
True
>>> numpy.isclose( 100000, 100000 + 1)   # very close!
True
>>> numpy.isclose( 100000, 100000 + 10)  # trips relative tolerance
False


see if you can convert the values to integers at a precise and known amount of imprecision (for example, if you have measurements in decimal meters, could they be made into integer μm?) and further try to avoid, manually simplify, and reorganize lossy operations (even/especially the humble division!) to best suit your accuracy needs


1 note that @Rahul kumar Gupta's Answer highlights that the algorithm backing sum() changes with 3.12, so you may find that the results even differ from their offset of 1 bit when retrying this exact case in older and newer versions of Python!
